# Express.js - foreach array of data and store them in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, bookshelf.js

I'm using expressjs, bookshelf.js and I want to post array of data, foreach such data and save it.

I'm not exactly sure where the issue is (express, bookshelf or just plain old javascript), but here's the scenario: when I post the said array and try to iterate through it, I get the correct amount of saves into the database, but all have the value of the last item in array.

Here's the code:

```
router.post('/save/', function(req, res){
    var data = req.body;
    var result = [];
    for (var i in data) {
        var d = data[i];
        if (d.user_id == -1) d.user_id = null;
        new Term().where({'date_of_driving': d.day})
        .fetch()
        .then(function(terms){
            if (terms != null) {
                return new Term({'id':terms.id}).save(d).then(function(item_updated){});
            } else {
                return new Term().save(d).then(function(item_saved){});               
           }
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    res.send({'saved': 'ok'});   
});
```

My understanding is, that these calls are asynchronous and always operate on the last data, because for sentence is quicker than save. Am I onto something?

What are some of the best, easiest and most correct solutions to this problem?

Comment: This [question&answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28478606/2241993) might help you understand your problem.

Comment: on this line: `return new Term({'id':term.id}).save(d).then(function(item_updated){});` `term` is undefined, and `d` doesn't reference what you want it to reference. Using a foreach as suggested by your title would solve that if request.body is an array.

Comment: Kevin B thanks for your response: that's a typo, I translated the code to English, and this got lost in there. I edited the code now. I don't understand exactly the second part of your answer - I am using a for sentence. As far as I know, there is no actually "foreach" in javascript. Or is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your code whether you want to the queries to be run in parallel or sequentially.

I am assuming parallel, but you can replace .map with .each and it will run sequentially

```
router.post('/save/', function(req, res){
    Promise.map(req.body, function(d) {
        if (d.user_id == -1) d.user_id = null;
        return new Term().where({'date_of_driving': d.day}).fetch().then(function(terms){
            if (terms != null) {
                return new Term({'id':terms.id}).save(d);
            } else {
                return new Term().save(d);    
            }
        });
    }).then(function() {
        res.send({'saved': 'ok'});
    }).catch(Promise.OperationalError, function(e) {
        // Note that stack reveals internal server code so you might
        // not want to send it over in production
        res.status(400).send({stack: e.stack, message: e.message});
    });
});
```

There is no need to catch an error only to log it so I removed it. Only catch an error when you can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the 'then' function will be executed asynchronously, and the loop will continue its execution independently, as you suspected.

I believe one solution is to define a function that will essentially take the parameter `d` as a reference and execute the asynchronous stuff with that. So this should work:

```
router.post('/save/', function(req, res){
    var data = req.body;
    var result = [];
    for (var i in data) {
        var d = data[i];
        if (d.user_id == -1) d.user_id = null;
        doTheThing(d);
    }
    res.send({'saved': 'ok'});   
});


function doTheThing(d) {
    new Term().where({'date_of_driving': d.day})
        .fetch()
        .then(function(terms){
            if (terms != null) {
                return new Term({'id':terms.id}).save(d).then(function(item_updated){});
            } else {
                return new Term().save(d).then(function(item_saved){});               
            }
        })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: How about using [Promise.map](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#mapfunction-mapper--object-options---promise)? Are they suppose to solve this kind of issues?

Comment: @uglycode I'm a bit of a beginner in node/promise programming, so I don't know the answer to that (I'd be also interested to learn about elegant solutions). I might look into that (I've been meaning to fully learn Bluebird's api), but meanwhile I added 'bluebird' and 'promise' as tags to your post (not visible until peer-reviewed), so let's see if someone else can chime in.