# How to design Mongoose methods that need to call save()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var SampleModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    values: [Number]
});

SampleModelSchema.methods.addValue = function(value){
    this.values.push(value);
    return this.save();
};

var SampleModel = mongoose.model('SampleModel', SampleModelSchema);
```

I want to add a method `addValue` to my mongoose schema.  I'm facing a dilemma here.  I can either put 'this.save()' in the method itself, or I can let the caller of this method call save.

If someone is using this model, I don't want them to have to remember to call save.  But the implementation as is is really bad if this method is called in a loop.

```
for(var k=0;k<10;k++){
    mySampleModel.addValue(k);
}
```

This will call save 10 times, which is bad for performance.

Is it best practice to never put `save()` in a method that can be called multiple times in a row and delegate the responsibility of saving to the caller?

Thanks!

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481228/804928) out